# Failing with valid code signing identity, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I intend to release an update for my iOS app Oskarshamnsliv to AppStore, but fail when I try. Since I last released an update **I have bought a new computer, which most probably is the cause of my problems.**

I have never before really understood what I have been doing when releasing and updating my apps. I have just used Ray Wenderlich's guides [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2). As I try to do the same again, **Xcode gives me an error message when I choose Product/Archive.**

[image: Xcode error alert]

Even though I press "Fix issue", the issue is not fixed. Anyway, I am sure the problem has something to do with with certificates/provisioning profiles which is further proved by the error description I get from Xcode:

[image: Xcode error description]

I have tried all sorts of things, and in despair I have also created new and deleted old certificates and provisioning profiles. **I have put some screenshots together to help make a clear picture of my situation.** I have spent too many hours on this now, any help will be much appreciated!

From build settings of my app:
[image]

From my Xcode organizer:
[image]

From my page on developer.apple.com:
[image]

From my page on developer.apple.com:
[image]

From my Keychain Access:
[image]

Comment: First, i suggest you go to preferences panel on Xcode under Accounts tab, click on 'View Details...' buttons under your account details, and click on the refresh button to make sure you have the most up to date profiles on your account. Second, i see that under Code Signing in your project settings, the 'Release' settings has different profiles set there under 'Any iOS SDK'.

Comment: @xicocaio Fantastic! As you guessed, the problem was that I had to put the same profile for 'Any iOS SDK'. I am so glad you helped me solve the issue. Not that glad I did not get any wiser though... :P

Comment: I Should have placed an answer... =/
Glad i helped anyway! =)

Comment: Write that as an answer and I'll accept it. You deserve the reputation, of course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, i suggest you go to preferences panel on Xcode under Accounts tab, click on 'View Details...' buttons under your account details, and click on the refresh button to make sure you have the most up to date profiles on your account.

Second, i see that under Code Signing in your project settings, the 'Release' settings has different profiles set there under 'Any iOS SDK'.